# The verse about the disobedience of the iblees

Tags: arabic, arabic-translation, surah

Ok. I know Al Baqarah 2:34 but there is something that feels wrong.

Allah ordered angels to prostrate after Hz Adam but The Iblees isn't a angel?

I have learned there is an rule in Arabic called Taqleeb (I like to see Quran as a... "Poetry Book" but the weirdness of Arabic makes me confused) but couldnt find it anywhere on the net from somewhere like a Arabic dictionary.

I want an explanation about the verse itself and the name of that Arabic writing rule.

Answer (score 1):

A translation of the verse is:

> And [mention] when We said to the angels, "Prostrate before Adam"; so they prostrated, except for Iblees. He refused and was arrogant and became of the disbelievers. (2:34)

Note the fact that Allah did not say "O Angels, prostrate before Adam." Allah simply said, in the direction of the angels, "Prostrate before Adam."

Since Iblis was among the angels at that time, this command was in his direction as well. He disobeyed this command.

The phrase "to the angels" is only in the narration of the story. It is a description of which group the command was said towards. But, the command wasn't limited to the species of the angels since Allah did not say "O Angels." Everyone who was among the angels was included in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Iblees is not an angle but from Al-Jinn and has been created from fire.

He (Iblees) used to worship Allah Almighty too much, and was too obedient and very close to Allah that He deserved from Allah to be put with the angles' class; thus, He was ordered the same command as what Allah ordered the angles since (*again*) He was classified with them. The [source_1 in Arabic](http://sderna.hooxs.com/t68-topic)

About **Taqleeb**, I have never heard of such a term, maybe you mean **Taddmeen** (تضمين) which indicates an implicit meaning in a particular word so that it would have two meanings. The [source_2 in Arabic](https://www.alukah.net/literature_language/0/92875/). But this has nothing to do with the verse.

Answer (score -2):

> I like to see the Qu'ran ... as a poetry book

There were plenty of poets in Arabia as oratory and poetry was a prized skill and this is still the case. However, the Prophet specifically denied he was one:

> And it is not the speech of a poet - little do you believe [69:41]

For many classical scholars Iblees was seen as an angel but more contemporary scholarship class him as a jinn.